# How to inspect userdata in lua

Tags: c, lua

I am using [inspect.lua](https://github.com/kikito/inspect.lua) to inspect table to string.

But, if the value is a userdata, it returns just `<userdata 1>`

I really need to know what the userdata type is, what the userdata value is, it's very important for debuging, I don't want do it in any IDE, I just want something can help me debug by print staffs.

Comment: The only info that you can get is from `getmetatable(someuserdata)`. What exactly do you want to inspect?

Comment: thanks a lot, there are something very useful, `print(inspect(getmetatable(someuserdata)))`

Comment: where "someuserdata" is what, exactly?. And the return value of getmetatable is what exactly? The manual is useless.

Answer (score 16):

You cannot.

From the [manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.1) :

> The type userdata is provided to allow arbitrary C data to be stored in Lua variables. A userdata value is a pointer to a block of raw memory. [...] Userdata has no predefined operations in Lua, except assignment and identity test.

As indicated by @Eric, the only thing you can do from Lua is inspect the metatable :

```
print(inspect(getmetatable(someuserdata)))
```

If you are using the C API, you should be able to register a custom function that prints whatever is held by the block.

Comment: and the identity test is?

Comment: @CashCow: The identity test is ==. That is, the expression (someuserdata == someuserdata) returns true, in my admittedly limited test. Looks like ~= also works.

Answer (score 0):

If the userdata metatable was created with `luaL_newmetatable` it contains an entry `__name` containing the userdatas type (since Lua version 5.3), see https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#luaL_newmetatable. Unfortunately this feature is still not widely used.